# C11 _Generic evaluating another macro

Tags: c, language-lawyer

I'd like to make `_Generic` evaluate another macro. In the example below, `db_put_u8` will insert a `uint8_t` into the buffer and while at it, it will also leave a log message. The log helps me understand if I missed a field. Hence the macro. I have reduced the functionality to illustrate the problem here, but in practice it's supposed to have for various data types.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define db_put_u8(con, name, val) \
    do { \
        fputs(name "<- " #val, con); \
    } while(0)

#define db_put(con, name, val) _Generic(val, uint8_t: db_put_u8)(con, name, val)

int main(void)
{
    uint8_t v = 10;
    db_put(stdout, "some-field", v);
    return 0;
}
```

When I try compiling this, I get an error:

```
test.c:15:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'db_put_u8'
    db_put(stdout, "some-field", v);
    ^
test.c:9:55: note: expanded from macro 'db_put'
#define db_put(con, name, val) _Generic(val, uint8_t: db_put_u8)(con, name, val)
                                                      ^
1 error generated.
```

Am I doing `_Generic` right? The [generic selection](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic) syntax does not explicitly restrict calling macros in it. Can someone explain what I am doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Replace `db_put_u8` with a function and it should work. You can do the stringification in another macro before passing the string to that function.

Comment: Note: neither the `_Generic` keyword itself nor generic selection expressions using it are macros or macro references.  Although they typically appear in macro replacement text, they themselves are evaluated (as if) after preprocessing.

Comment: did you expect the output be `some_field-> v` or `some_field-> 10`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```c
#define db_put(con, name, val) _Generic(val, uint8_t: db_put_u8)(con, name, val)
```

First of all has to change to:

```
#define db_put(con, name, val) _Generic(val, uint8_t: db_put_u8(con, name, val))
```

Because `_Generic` works at compile time, not preprocessor time. And after preprocessing, `db_put_u8` will not expand because it doesn't exist as a macro. `db_put_u8(arg1, arg2, arg3)`, however, does, so you have to put the brackets in the generic. However, there's another error then: `_Generic` expects an eression, so a `do while` loop would not work. In this case though, you don't even need to encase your macro in a loop because it's just one statement, so it's free from the potential issues of macros with many statements. Your final program should look something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define db_put_u8(con, name, val) \
        fputs(name "<- " #val, con)

#define db_put(con, name, val) _Generic(val, uint8_t: db_put_u8(con, name, val))

int main(void)
{
    uint8_t v = 10;
    db_put(stdout, "some-field", v);
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** In response to the comment, there is a solution. So long as the second thing to do in `db_put_u8` is also a statement, you could use the comma operator and a few more brackets. Here's an example program to put it to the test:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define db_put_u8(con, name, val) \
   (fputs(name "<- " #val, con), \
    fputs("\nAnother test line\n", con))

#define db_put(con, name, val) \
    (_Generic(val, uint8_t: db_put_u8(con, name, val)))

int main(void)
{
    uint8_t v = 10;
    db_put(stdout, "some-field", v);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this, it outputs:

```
some-field<- v
Another test line
```

Comment: I think I wasn't clear. Sorry about that. The `db_put_u8` macro has 2 things to do. Not just the log part. This is why there's a `do {...} while`.

Comment: @UnmannedPlayer I've edited my post, does it work for your issue now?

Answer (score 0):

Macro db_put_u8 would expand as `do ... while(...)` statement which is not an expression. `_Generic` expects expression thus error is observed. You should provide a function named `db_put_u8`. The function name decays to pointer to the function which is an an expression.

Other way around is to replace db_put_u8 with 'fputs(name "<- " #val, con)' inside _Generic and remove final '(name, val,con)'

```c
    #define db_put(con, name, val) \
        _Generic(val, uint8_t: fputs(name "<- " #val, con))
```

If `db_put_u8` cannot be changed then one could use an C extension named `statement expression`. It is supported by GCC and CLANG. Basically it allows to put arbitrary statement info `({ ... })`. The last expression evaluated is returned as result.

```c
    #define db_put(con, name, val) \
        _Generic(val, uint8_t: ({db_put_u8(con, name, val);}))
```

Comment: I thought so too at first but it's not even that - `db_put_u8` doesn't appear in function-call-like context so it's not expanded at all.  Similar to the way that `(db_put_u8)(foo,bar,baz)` would not be expanded.